# how to get connectionaborted immediately in Asynchronous Programming?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I was doing Asynchronous Programming in c# when I came across this question,when the network is aborted.

My program can get a exception of ConnectionAborted almost  15 seconds after I send a invaild message from client to server.

My question is if I want to get the exception immediately after the network doesn't work,what need I do.

```
namespace _10_TCP模块化编程
{
class ObjectState
{
    public Socket client;

    public MyTcp obj;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.     
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.     
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
class MyTcp
{
    public delegate void dReceiver(object sender, string b);
    public event dReceiver receive;
    public Socket WebHabor;
    //private bool connected;
    public MyTcp(IPEndPoint iep, dReceiver dEventCall)
    {

        //接收消息的委托;
        receive += dEventCall;
        //创建socket连接;
        WebHabor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ObjectState obs = new ObjectState();
        obs.obj = this;
        obs.client = WebHabor;
        WebHabor.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), obs);
        //connected = WebHabor.Connected ? true : false;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        if (WebHabor.Connected == true)
        {
            Receive();
        }
        else
        {
            Program.postLog("连接失败，请检查ip和port");
        }
    }
    public static void ExceptionSolver(SocketException sep)
    {
        switch (sep.SocketErrorCode)
        {
            case SocketError.NotConnected:
                //捕获ip地址输入错误的情况;
                Program.postLog("不存在网络连接");
                break;

            case SocketError.ConnectionAborted:
                //在这里处理频繁出现的错误，
                //比如IP不对，网线没插
                Program.postLog("连接中止");
                break;
            case SocketError.ConnectionRefused:
                //远程主机正在主动拒绝连接;可能是连接的时候ip或port写错了;
                Program.postLog("对方不接受连接,更可能是port的原因");
                break;
            case SocketError.HostUnreachable:
                Program.postLog("连接目标不可达");
                break;
            case SocketError.TimedOut:
                //尝试连接ip超时;
                Program.postLog("尝试连接ip超时,更可能是ip的原因");
                break;
            default:
                Program.postLog("捕获到" + sep.SocketErrorCode);
                //这里直接报错，如果调试的时候出现这里的错误比较多，就移到上面解决，一般问题都是从来不出的
                break;

        }
    }


    public void Send(byte[] dataToSend,int byteCount)
    {

        try
        {
            WebHabor.BeginSend(dataToSend, 0, byteCount, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), WebHabor);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);//为了让其它线程跑起来;
        }
        catch (SocketException sep)
        {
            Program.postLog("在Send这里");
            ExceptionSolver(sep);
        }
    }
    public void Receive()
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

        ObjectState obs = new ObjectState();
        obs.obj = this;//这个传的是MyTcp;
        obs.client = WebHabor;

        try
        {
            WebHabor.BeginReceive(obs.buffer, 0, ObjectState.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), obs);
        }
        catch (SocketException sep)
        {
            Program.postLog("在reveive这里");
            ExceptionSolver(sep);
        }
        //receive.Invoke(this, buffer);
    }



    //beginConnect的回调函数;
    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ObjectState obs = (ObjectState)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.     

            Socket client = obs.client;
            // Complete the connection.     
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            //Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            //连上就连上吧就不发数据了
            //MessageBox.Show("Socket connected to " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            // Signal that the connection has been made.     
            //connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (SocketException sep)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show("connect回调函数出错了" + e.ToString());
            /*********************************************************************
             * 
             * 此处需要考察一下连接失败的异常情况。
             * 
             *********************************************************************/
            //obs.obj.connected = false;
            Program.postLog("在ConnectCallback这里");
            ExceptionSolver(sep);
        }

    }
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.     
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);//为了让其它线程跑起来;
            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.     
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Program.postLog("本次发送" + bytesSent + "个字节");
            //Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
            //MessageBox.Show("Sent " + bytesSent + " bytes to server.");
            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.     
            //sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (SocketException sep)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Send回调函数出错了" + e.ToString());
            /*********************************************************************
             * 
             * 此处需要考察一下发送失败的异常情况。
             * 
             *********************************************************************/
            Program.postLog("在SendCallback这里");
            ExceptionSolver(sep);
        }
    }
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket     
            // from the asynchronous state object.     
            //StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            //Socket client = state.workSocket;
            // Read data from the remote device.    
            ObjectState objs = (ObjectState)ar.AsyncState;

            Socket client = objs.client;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.     
                string getMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objs.buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                //Console.WriteLine("新得到的数据是" + getMsg + "呵呵");
                //MessageBox.Show("新得到的数据是" + getMsg);
                string msg=Encoding.Default.GetString(objs.buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                Program.postLog(msg);
                //objs.obj.receive.Invoke(objs.obj, msg);//因为这是静态函数,这个objs.obj实际是MyTcp实例。
                //MessageBox.Show(bytesRead.ToString() + "更新数据后:" + state.sb.ToString());
                // Get the rest of the data.     
                client.BeginReceive(objs.buffer, 0, objs.buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), objs);

            }
            else
            {
                //接到0字节说明对方主动断开了连接;
                Program.postLog("对方主动断开连接");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException sep)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Receive回调函数出错了" + e.ToString());
            /*********************************************************************
             * 
             * 此处需要考察一下接收失败的异常情况。
             * 
             *********************************************************************/
            Program.postLog("在ReceiveCallback这里");
            ExceptionSolver(sep);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can try using TcpClient.Client.Poll method as mentioned in one of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784388/c-sharp-while-remote-tcp-connection).