# TcpClient.Connected Always True

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I have a fairly simple client/server architecture using TCP client. The server is set up to close connections from clients it hasn't received a message from in two minutes. I have verified that this works fine using a C++ TCP client for my Android device. However, my C# client always appears to be connected, even after the server closes the connection.

I've tried a variety of things and none of them seem to accurately report that the connection has been closed. TcpClient.Connected always returns true, even after sending and receiving messages, [unlike what is specified in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected.aspx). C# Client code:

```
var client = new TcpClient(server, port);
var stream = client.GetStream();

//Wait >2 mins to get disconnected
await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromMinutes(2.5));

void Write()
{
    try
    {
        var data = BuildByteArrayFromMyData();
        stream.Write(data , 0, data.Length);

        if(!client.Connected)
        {
            //Never triggered, Connected always equals true
        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Never triggered
    }
}

void ReadOnAnotherThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                if (!client.Connected) break; //Never triggered, Connected always equals true
                else await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(11));
            }

            byte[] data = new byte[];
            int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
         }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Never triggered
    }
}
```

---

**Q: What is the correct way to use TcpClient.Connected?**

---

Similar questions that do NOT answer the question proposed here:

- [No accepted answer, does not address the question of why TcpClient.Connected is always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387459/how-to-check-if-tcpclient-connection-is-closed)

---

Comment: the code you added doesn't make much sense...I don't see you closing the connection like you claim you do

Comment: This is the client code. The connection is closed by the server.

Comment: There is no correct way to use `TcpClient.Connected`. It's a very misleading property name, which should actually be called `TcpClient.UsedToBeConnectedAtSomePointInThePastAndAsFarAsIKnowItStillIsButImNotSure`. In other words, it's practically useless. To detect dropped connections, the best option is to send data at regular intervals, as I [describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).