# Missing method exception in .net core

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

I think this may have something to do with the dependencies, but I'm not really sure.

So I'm trying to check to see if a TCP connection is still active using the extension method I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387459/how-to-check-if-tcpclient-connection-is-closed), but I'm getting a missing method exception:

"Method not found: 'System.Net.IPEndPoint System.Net.NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation.get_LocalEndPoint()'"

Which I'm a little confused on since the method [seems to exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.net.networkinformation.tcpconnectioninformation#System_Net_NetworkInformation_TcpConnectionInformation_LocalEndPoint).

Here's the code:

```
 public static TcpState GetState(this TcpClient tcpClient)
        {

                var status = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
                                               .GetActiveTcpConnections()
                                               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.LocalEndPoint.Equals(tcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint));

                return status != null ? status.State : TcpState.Unknown;

        }
```

and the JSON file where I think there might be a problem in how NetworkInformation is referenced:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "system.net.networkinformation": "4.0.10-beta-23123"

  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

Am I on the right track? How would I fix it?

Comment: Did you double check that your version is the same as the one that supports that code?

Comment: I know it's not the same version, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpconnectioninformation.localendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to be consistent.

Comment: 4.0.10-beta-23123, ugh, those version numbers make anybody's eyes bleed.  Looks like you just kept digging for a reference assembly until the compiler was happy.  That the runtime isn't happy is not a great mystery.  The documentation makes no bones about it either, only available on the full desktop version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: @HansPassant ok so I was on the right track. I was getting an error that TcpState could not be found and adding that dependency seemed to fix it. So I need to get the full version? what version am I using?

Comment: try adding `system.net.security` package also, as `networkinformation` depends on `security` package. It might not be loaded dependencies automatically.

Comment: @Venky where exactly? in the dependencies?

Comment: @Venky yeah I guess that fixed it. I also got rid of the beta version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `system.net.security` package also, as `system.net.networkinformation` depends on security package. It might not have loaded dependencies automatically.