# C# ClientWebSocket retry after connection error

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, slack, clientwebsocket

Is there any way to know whether ClientWebSocket connection is closed/disconnected? I am using slack RTM api in C# and sometimes due to connectivity issues connection is closed from server, then I want to retry connection.

I am connecting to websocket server like this

```
var client = new ClientWebSocket();
client.ConnectAsync(url, token);
```

Comment: It is not the same way that most async socket science works; upon disconnect the delegate attached to the receive event runs, but receives 0 bytes?

Comment: A websocket uses TCP as the transport layer.  So following posting may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387459/how-to-check-if-tcpclient-connection-is-closed