# How can I make a server print a notification as soon as a client connects to it?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

Take a look at the following two programs:

```
//Server

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyServerProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            int port = 2000;
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
            listener.Start();

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(netStream);

            try
            {
                while (client.Client.Connected)
                {
                    string str = br.ReadString();

                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                br.Close();
                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}

//Client

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyClientProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 2000;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port);

            NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();

            BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(netStream);

            try
            {
                int i=1;
                while (client.Client.Connected)
                {
                    br.Write(i.ToString());
                    br.Flush();
                    i++;

                    int milliseconds = 2000;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                br.Close();
                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These programs are working fine.

Suppose, at this point of this program, I need the server to print a message on the screen as soon as a client gets connected to it, and, also when the client is disconnected.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: in your code client is connected after `TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();` and disconnected once you exit while loop or inside catch block; check it too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387459/how-to-check-if-tcpclient-connection-is-closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AcceptTcpClient` blocks execution and starts waiting for connection. So right after it you can write message that client `connected`. Also you could write connected client address. Just for information, but sometimes it could be helpful.

```
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
ShowMessage("Connected " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address);
```

For detect client disconnect you could catch exceptions. Change your `catch` like this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    var inner = ex.InnerException as SocketException;
    if (inner != null && inner.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
        ShowMessage("Disconnected");
    else
        ShowMessage(ex.Message);
...
```