# detect lost server connection

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, client

I'm working on a client/server game and am looking for ways for the client to detect whether it is still connected to the server, like for example when the server is power down.
Right now all I can think of is passing a token over time from server to client to tell the client that it is still connected. What I want to ask is whether anyone can tell me a better way of doing server connection checks. Can someone please give me some advise?

Comment: **How** are you connected? E.g. is there a TCP connection?

Comment: Yes, on the server I have a tcp listener and on the client side I am using socket to connect

Comment: then you could probably use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387459/7111561). Instead of a passive receiving timer you simply can check continuously active if the server is still connected

Comment: Ok, I'll check this out first then. Thx