# Socket connection status in a server-client application

Tags: c#, sockets

i have a server which receives datas from a large number of clients (200).
it is just a receiver of datas from clients, if the client is disconnected 
how can the server come to know that the client is not present.

Comment: i need the answer boss what do u want me to do

Comment: Try the answers from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515458/how-can-i-check-whether-a-tcp-socket-is-disconnected-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Here's great load of stuff related to sockets. If you can't find your answer here you're probably doing something wrong :)
http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=3021

here's your specific:
http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=2935